# Ubuntu 20.04 x11vnc black screen with lightdm

Tags: 20.04, lightdm, vnc

I am running a fresh installation of 20.04. I am new to this, so I followed [this video](https://davidbombal.com/ubuntu-vnc-server/) for installing x11vnc.
The problem I'm facing is that the screen shows black on the remote pc when there is no display attached to the target pc. But the moment I connect the HDMI cable to the target pc, the display also shows up on the remote pc.

There are a lot of questions with the same black screen issue, but I can't figure out what solution to use as all are different, and I don't understand the parameters.

Only one I have used so far is the `chmod 775 xstartup` but that didn't help.
Please assist